# Convert 2 columns to a list in R?

Tags: r, list

If I have this:

```
 vol=list() ;df=data.frame(name=c(5,2,15,4),name=c(2,0,1,2))
```

I want to add this to vol, I tried but

```
   vol[[1]]= unclass(df)
```

The output is not what i wanted

I need the out put to be like this:

```
$name (i need to add this title here, the first name)
name name.1
 5      2
 2      0
 15      1
 4      2
```

Comment: please elaborate "is not what i wanted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap it in `list`

```
vol <- setNames(list(df), names(df)[1])
```

or create the `list` and set the names later

```
vol <- list(df)
names(vol)[1] <- names(df)[1]
```

Or if the object is a NULL list

```
vol<-list() 
vol[[names(df)[1]]] <- df
```

-output

```
> vol
$name
  name name.1
1    5      2
2    2      0
3   15      1
4    4      2
```

---

Or may also use `:=` with `dplyr::lst`

```
vol <- dplyr::lst(!! names(df)[1] := df)
```

Comment: @Tpellirn Did you meant `vol=list();
> vol[["name"]] = df;`

Comment: Yes exact but  i need vol[["name"]]  to take the name of the first column not to put it like this by hand.

Comment: @Tpellirn the update should help

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `lapply`:

```
lapply(df, `[`)

$name
[1]  5  2 15  4

$name.1
[1] 2 0 1 2
```